# How do Resolve the Following Error When Installing Twisted by Pip?

Tags: twisted

I am unable to install Twisted. I've looked at other posts but I'm unable to ascertain what's wrong. Can someone help?

```
  Building wheel for twisted (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/scrapy-woEp5YDx/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/3w/vpvs85311y7220v_grhz7y940000gn/T/pip-install-m3lb3nv6/twisted/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/3w/vpvs85311y7220v_grhz7y940000gn/T/pip-install-m3lb3nv6/twisted/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/3w/vpvs85311y7220v_grhz7y940000gn/T/pip-wheel-io9a11t0
       cwd: /private/var/folders/3w/vpvs85311y7220v_grhz7y940000gn/T/pip-install-m3lb3nv6/twisted/
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question.  Include your OS, the version of all your tools, the full command you ran, and the full output, including any log files written.  Also consider adding any debug- or verbosity-enabling options to whatever command you're running.